# how to change the text assigned to a variable in batch

Tags: batch-file

So I am having a problem with changing a text assinged using the set /a
here is my script

```
:wep
cls
if %gold% lss 50 (
echo not enough gold
pause >nul
goto shop
)
if %weap%==Stick (
echo too low on level
pause >nul
goto shop
)
if %wepugrd% lss 1 (
echo You don't have any upgrades
pause
goto shop
)
cls
echo Your Weapon is Being Upgraded
echo.
echo WAIT A FEW SECONDS
ping localhost -n 3 >nul
set /a weapdmg=%weapdmg% + 5
set /a weap=Stick
set /a wepugrd=%wepugrd% - 1
set /a gold=%gold% - 50
echo weapon upgraded
pause
goto shop
```

the last part is set /a weap=Stick
it was earlier fist
but instead it just changes fist to 0 instead of changing it to stick
can I get some help with that
thanx

Comment: `set weap=Stick`  - /a switch is for arithmetic operations only.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
:wep
cls
if %gold% lss 50 (
    echo not enough gold
    pause >nul
    goto shop
)
if "%weap%"=="Stick" (
    echo too low on level
    pause >nul
    goto shop
)
if %wepugrd% lss 1 (
    echo You don't have any upgrades
    pause
    goto shop
)
cls
echo Your Weapon is Being Upgraded
echo.
echo WAIT A FEW SECONDS
%SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe localhost -n 3 >nul
set /a weapdmg+=5
set "weap=Stick"
set /a wepugrd-=1
set /a gold-=50
echo weapon upgraded
pause
goto shop
```

As [npocmaka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388389/npocmaka) wrote, switch `/A` is only for arithmetic operations and can't be used if just a string should be assigned to a variable.

Adding or subtracting an integer to an existing value can be also done using the short form as demonstrated above.

And read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) for reason enclosing `weap=Stick` in double quotes.